# How to increase Unitys search timeout?

Tags: unity, timeout

My laptop is not the fastest, especially when I'm running low on memory. This makes Unity timing out to soon when I try to start an application, for example. It just displays no results. How can I increase the timeout?

Comment: What version of ubuntu and unity are you using? Are you sure that the timeout is the issue and not the application being installed/found?

Comment: 13.04... The application can be found when no programs are open. As soon as I open a browser, eclipse, Thunderbird and maybe watch a video, the timeout becomes an issue.